# Motorcycle battery empty after driving?

Tags: motorcycle, battery

I had a strange problem with the battery of my motorcycle and I'd like to understand what was going on from the physical point of view:
When I started the motorcycle in the morning (or better: after the motor didn't run for several hours) I had no problems while the startup process. It worked as expected. 
After I drove, let's say 30 min and turned off the engine and tried to start again (for example at the fuel station), the battery was totally empty. No energy, nothing. BUT when I drove to work and tried to start after 8 hours to drive back home, I was able to start. Does anybody have an idea what is going on here? Usually it is the other way around with a defective battery (you cannot start in the morning, but you can start after you drove a while).
Nevertheless, after I installed a new battery, I didn't have this problem any more, so it was definitively the battery, but can anybody explain that?
(The service guy told me that this could have anything to do with the heat of the engine which is near the battery, but I'm not very confident with this theory)

Comment: @WrichikBasu No, because this is a common physical issue and not a question about how I repair a motorcycle.

Comment: No, it's not. We don't know what physics is going on inside a motorcycle. That's dealt at the above mentioned site. They'll help you in the best way possible.

Comment: @WrichikBasu This question is about the physics inside a battery. But if you think it doesn't belong here, then move it to Motor Vehicles group.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the battery. But a battery can't just lose charge like that. Maybe the dynamo isn't working properly all the time, or there are problems in terminals or battery water level. I **feel** it'll be better on motor vehicle SE, because I've seen similar questions there. Just post this question there. If you get good response from any of these two sites, delete the question from the other site.

Comment: I don't know that anyone would be able to tell you without interacting with the battery and motorcycle itself.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a faulty battery - no power at all then power is fine.

This could be a broken internal link in the battery.

Difficult to test though, take it out, connect a headlight bulb to it an gently tap it, wobble it etc. This will by no meams be conclusive though...

If you can get a new or borrow another battery that will be the best test ie see if it does it with a different battery.

And, it could also be a broken lead to the battery - wiggle them to find out - again not always conclusive...

Comment: It's surely the battery. Because my new battery works without errors, so it's not actually a Motorcycle problem. That's why I posted this in "physics" at first, because I wanted to understand, what's happening inside the battery, since it's not working after driving, but it's working after I didn't drive for several hours.

Comment: @Bevor So, the part where I say "broken internal link" may be relevant then...

Comment: Yes, although I'd like to understand, why there was power to start the engine after the engine didn't run for hours, but why there was absolutely no power when I stopped the engine and tried to start it immediately again.

Comment: The broken link can break or make as it gets disturbed ...